# How to Compare a string to see if the characters entered before '$' are equal to the ones after it?

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stack

I've been implementing an algorithm for a book which is as follows :

L = {w$w' : w is a possibly empty string of characters than $ w' = reverse(w)}

Following the books pseudocode I wrote the code for my program that would take a string you entered like for example ( A$A,ABC$CBA)  and compare the characters before and after the $ to determine if they're a palindrome. I wrote the code exactly as was instructed by the book but the program is not working correctly. No matter what I enter it always returns false.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code I wrote :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "stack.h"
#include <string>
using namespace std;

bool isInLanguage(string aString)
{
  Stack<char> aStack;

  int i = 0;
  // ch is aString[i]
  while( aString[i] != '$')
  {
      aStack.push(aString[i]);
      ++i;
  }

  //skip the $
  ++i;

  //match the reverse of w
  bool inLanguage = true; // assume string is in language
  while(inLanguage && i < aString.length())
  {

      char stackTop;
      aStack.pop(stackTop);
      if(stackTop == aString[i])
          ++i; //characters match
      else
          //top of stack is not aString[i]
          inLanguage = false; //reject string
      if(aStack.isEmpty())
  {
      //pop failed, stack is empty. first half of string
      //is shorter than second half)
      inLanguage = false;
  } // end if

  } // end while
   if (inLanguage && aStack.isEmpty())
          return true;
      else
          return false;
} // end isInLanguage

int main()
{
    string str;
    bool boolean;
    cout << "Enter a string to be checked by the algorithm : ";
    cin >> str;
    boolean = isInLanguage(str);
    if (boolean == true)
        cout << "The string is in language.\n";
    else 
        cout << "The string is not in language.\n";
    return 0;
```

}

Comment: Did you try stepping through this under the Visual Studio debugger, using some simple test cases?  That will be the most educational thing you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Even after popping the last character from string you are checking `if(aStack.IsEmpty())` which will return true which in turn sets `inLanguage` to `false`. So even if the string was a palindrome you still set the `inLanguage` to `false` after popping last character.

Answer (score 1):

you haven't reinitialized variable i = 0 before the while loop of pop operation.

```
....
 ++i; 

  //match the reverse of w 
  bool inLanguage = true; // assume string is in language 
  while(inLanguage && i < aString.length()) 
  { 
 .....
```

according to the your code the condition `i < aString.length` in the while loop will always be false.

try this before the while loop..

```
i = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your logic in `while` loop is wrong, just like Naveen said. Consider what happens with a simple case of a$a:

```
push 'a' in the stack
skip $
pop 'a' and compare with 'a' -> inLanguage == true
stack is empty -> inLanguage == false
```

This is clearly not what you want. You need to test the stack size in the loop's condition. I'd simplify the loop to something like this:

```
while (i < aString.size() && !aStack.isEmpty()) {
    char stackTop;
    aStack.pop(stackTop);
    if(stackTop != aString[i]) break;
    ++i;  
}

if (i == aString.size() && aStack.isEmpty())
    return true;
else
    return false;
```